# How to separate canvas update logic from rAF drawing updates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on my second big canvas project (a game) and are really trying to optimize everything.

I have my mouse and keyboard listeners set up so they change the state of my canvas layers but all drawing is done through my rAF call. This works well.

However, I'd like to do a similar thing with the rest of my game. Could I add an event listener or somehow update all my states/variables after each rAF call completes drawing?

For example, if something must move five pixels left I currently do the subtraction then draw. I would like to be able to do the subtraction after each frame outside the rAF and then inside of it just draw, draw, draw. No calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, how is a `move-left-5-pixels` triggered (keystroke, mouse, just elapsed time)? If the triggers are events (key,mouse) then you can safely do `gamepiece.x-=5` inside the event handlers and rAF will redraw gamepiece at its new `x` location when rAF executes.  If pieces move based on time, then updating inside rAF is appropriate. Keep in mind that rAF receives a `timestamp` with each loop. You can use this timestamp to calculate elapsed time and use that elapsed time to reposition any time-dependent pieces. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hmmmm. That's probably a poor example... So each section of the game works as a scene. When the user reaches the very edge of the screen is pushes the current scene left and pulls the next one in the from the right. Nice and smooth. So I set each scene to a target position and it figures out if the current position is more or less than where it needs to go, then it changes the x position by positive or negative five. UNLESS the current position is the target position then it just exits the method without redrawing.  I have more complex cases similar to this with several if else statements.

Comment: Sorry this is such a pain to explain. Lemme know if I need to clear anything up.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you "stitch" previous & next scenes together based on a target position? Does each scene have static parts (eg a background) and fluid parts (eg. moving characters)?

Comment: Yes. Each scene contains several layered canvases depending on the complexity of it. Some parts are static and some need constantly updated. Some, such as the character respond to events.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both. Save variables based on events and draw then with rAF. 
see the link below. (the 2 sec loop should be your rAF)
[Canvas animation frame rendering: Infinite Loop vs. triggering on mousemover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015240/canvas-animation-frame-rendering-infinite-loop-vs-triggering-on-mousemover/25016009#25016009)

(not my best code work)